# Can I load more process into GPU if RAM is free but GPU Util is showing almost full?

Tags: nvidia, gpu

`nvidia-smi` is showing as

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro K620         On   | 00000000:02:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 65%   74C    P0    20W /  30W |    758MiB /  1994MiB |     98%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1314      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            31MiB |
|    0      1927      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           187MiB |
|    0      2139      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         248MiB |
|    0      4055      G   ...AAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAA= --shared-files    85MiB |
|    0      5824      G   /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer              8MiB |
|    0     14613      C   gmx                                           73MiB |
|    0     21803      G   /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio                  59MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see `GPU util` is showing 98%

But RAM is still free - `758MiB /  1994MiB`

What does exactly `GPU-Util` mean? Can I load one more process into the GPU now?

Especially I wish to load a molecular dynamics simulation to GPU. (`gmx`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GPU-Util` is [the percentage of time, over the last sample period, during which at least one kernel was running on the GPU](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DCGM/docs/nvidia-smi-367.38.pdf).

98% means that your GPU is being used nearly all the time, probably by `gmx`, so there might not be any spare capacity to run another compute task.